# create menu from taxonomy/term in drupal 7

Tags: menu, drupal-7, taxonomy

in the documentation site of drupal:

http://drupal.org/node/774892

It shows an example of how to create a menu using taxonomies. Basically we must add a link to an url like taxonomy/term/{termID}/all . But it says it can not work with drupal 7. is there any other way to make that menu from a hierarchical taxonomy?

Thank you

Comment: You might be looking for the [Taxonomy Menu module](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu)

Comment: Is any other way to do that without use that module?

Comment: @sonseiya why you don't want to use the module? Any particular drawback?

Comment: You can achieve this without taxonomy menu module, but in fact, it does exactly what you asked for : it turn taxonomy into menu.


You can succeed in without this module, but you'll should rewrote something very close to the module ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a module [Taxonomu menu](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu). You can generate menu for any vocabylary.

> Transform any of your taxonomy vocabularies into existing menus
>   easily!

P.S. I use 7.x-1.x-dev release instead of recommended. There are more options

Answer (score 0):

You can use Taxonomy menu module for the same.

Comment: this should be in comment part.